# Unable to understand the flow control in java

Tags: java, boolean

I am able to solve the attached code from a coding website.However,My answer is different from the website's answer.Below posted is the code.

```
static boolean b1, b2;
public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    int x = 0;
    if ( !b1 ) /* Line 7 */
    {
        if ( !b2 ) /* Line 9 */
        {
            b1 = true;
            x++;
            if ( 5 > 6 ) 
            {
                x++;
            }
            if ( !b1 ) 
                x = x + 10;
            else if ( b2 = true ) /* Line 19 */
                x = x + 100;
            else if ( b1 | b2 ) /* Line 21 */
                x = x + 1000;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

My idea:

> Initially,b1=false and b2= false,it passes the first two if conditions 
>           and sets b1 to true besides incrementing the value of x to >1. From there on it  starts failing for every condition and prints the >final value to be 1.

Website's Solution:

> As instance variables, b1 and b2 are initialized to false. The if tests
>           on lines 7 and 9 are successful so b1 is set to true and x is
>          incremented. The next if test to succeed is on line 19 (note >that the
>          code is not testing to see if b2 is true, it is setting b2 to be >true).
>          Since line 19 was successful, subsequent else-if's (line 21) >will be
>          skipped.The final value of x is 101

What I do not understand from the website solution:

> "note that the code is not testing to see if b2 is true, it is setting 
>            b2 to be true".
>           How can it set the value of b2 to "true"  without testing it's status?

Any Suggestions can be highly helpful!

Comment: The quotes should be quotes, not code

Comment: It's a way to test the reader's attentiveness, it's using ```b2 = true``` instead of ```b2 == true```, so b2 gets assigned true.

Comment: Check the number of =.

Comment: You your favorite IDE and debug this. Code with `if / else` is formatted that way that it gives false impression which else belongs where. Use curly braces after each conditions for clarity.

Comment: @MirMasej Sure that will help, but the cheap trick in here ... you just need to read with all eyes fully open ... and count = characters carefully.

Comment: I was trying to give a fish pole instead of a fish on a plate ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 19 is:

```
else if ( b2 = true )
```

The coding website is probably trying to teach you about a common programming mistake, ie. using assignment `=` instead of comparison `==`.

The code (as written above) is assigning the value of `true` to `b2` rather than comparing the value of `b2` to `true`. The result of the assignment expression is `true` hence the `if` will always succeed and its code block will be executed. This will happen regardless of the value of `b2` prior to executing this line of code.

If you use what was probably intended, ie:

```
else if ( b2 == true )
```

then a comparison will take place and the `if` expression (and the execution of its block) will depend on the value of `b2`.